# How to make this javascript skip the first tr in a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, html-table

How can I skip the first `<tr>` of my table? Actually, it is skipping my heading row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#myTable tr").filter(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$()` for `DOMContent` ready event instead of `$(document).ready` `function`.
`$.filter` should be return `boolean`. But, you didn't. `$.filter` redundant here. Use `$.each` `function` for dom element iteration. Try as below _

```
$(function () {
    $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        const $el = $("#myTable");
        $('tr', $el).not($('tr:first-child', $el)/*skip first tr*/).each(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
        // or
        $('tr', $el).not('tr:first'/*skip first tr*/).each(function () {
            $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that by using the following pseudos:

```
#mytable tr:not:first-child
```

Comment: `#mytable tr:not:first-child` given dom selector is not valid !